# Python - Reading Specific Info from a File

Tags: python

What I need to do is read information from a text file that I have been given.  It is in this format:

```
<theme>
<# of items>,<price>,<# of items>,<price> etc etc.
<theme>
<# of items>,<price>,<# of items>,<price> etc etc.
<theme>
<# of items>,<price>,<# of items>,<price> etc etc.
```

and it continues on.

I know how to open the file for reading, that is the simple part.  But what I need to do is read the theme names, set them to an integer, print them to the screen and have a user choose from them.  I also need to be able to take the info from the line below the theme that the user has chosen.

What would be a good way to go about this?

Comment: any try by yourself ?

Comment: Hint: use a dictionary, where the keys are the theme names, and the values are tuples of the attributes of the given theme.

Comment: There are two ways to get started here. The first is to write a `while True:` loop around `theme = f.readline(); details = f.readline(); if not theme: break`. The second is to think of the file like an iterable and look at how to group any iterable into pairs (see the recipes in the itertools docs if you can't figure it out yourself); then you can just loop over the pairs.